# Postgresql group by relation

Tags: postgresql, group-by, typeorm

I want to group the records by relation.

products table:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |

product_properties table:

| id | productId | propertyId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 4 |

The query should select lowest price group by product_properties. I mean, If products have same properties in product_properties, query should return product that has lowest price.

So, For these tables query should return products that have ids 1,3.

I use TypeORM, I tried join the relation and distinct on relation alias name but its not worked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote two variants query for you:

```
-- variant 1 
select distinct t1.product_id from (
    select 
        pr.price, pp.product_id, pp.property_id, min(pr.price) OVER(PARTITION BY pp.property_id) as min_price
    from 
        test.product_properties pp 
    inner join 
        test.products pr on pp.product_id = pr.id 
) t1  
where 
    t1.price = t1.min_price;
    

-- variant 2 
select distinct t1.product_id from test.product_properties t1
inner join test.products t2 on t1.product_id = t2.id 
inner join (
    select 
        pp.property_id, min(pr.price) as min_price  
    from 
        test.product_properties pp 
    inner join 
        test.products pr on pp.product_id = pr.id 
    group by pp.property_id
) t3 on t3.property_id = t1.property_id and t3.min_price = t2.price;
```